# Adding highscore via AJAX to a database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I have a canvas game that I have created and placed in a website. When a player gets a highscore I am wanting to post the new highscore to a database I have created. The partial script of my game (the bit that I want to send to the highscore database) is as follows:

```
var scoreArray = [];

$.get('api/listScores.php', function(myData){

    $.each(myData, function(name, val){
        console.info(name);
        console.info(val);
        var tempHTML = "";
        //loop through the data
        $.each(myData, function(name, val){
            //store a reference to the score
            scoreArray.push(val);
            tempHTML +='<li>';
            tempHTML +='<span>';
            tempHTML += val.dbScore;
            tempHTML +='</span>'
            tempHTML +='<span>'
            tempHTML += val.dbPlayer;
            tempHTML +='</span>'
            tempHTML +='</li>'
        });
        $('.highScores').html(tempHTML);
    });

    // scoreArray now has a value
    var lastItem = scoreArray.pop();

    //check if function scope 'score' or global scope 'score' is greater than the object 'lastItem.dbScore'.
    if (score > lastItem.dbScore)
    {
        $.post('api/addNewHighScore.php', 
            {   
                gamePlayer: playerName,
                gameScore: score
            } 
        );
    }
});
```

In 'api/listScore.php' I have listed the rows of my database in descending order.

The error I am currently getting is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dbScore' of undefined

This error refers to the line:

```
if (score > lastItem.dbScore)
```

Does this mean that scoreArray.pop() is not working?
Should I be tackling this in a different way?

*Apologies that not all the code is here, there are a lot of source code files and lines of code that I can't put into one post.*

Comment: have you logged the lastItem into console and checked what it is holding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get` is asynchronous, so `lastItem` is taken before the actual array is populated. Move your line setting lastItem and checking/setting high score to the end of your get request callback.

Comment: Many thanks this has solved my error, still having problems but that's with other bits of code, it's turning into a right nightmare this project.

Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to have helped out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pop removes the last element of an array, it does not select the last element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: The value returned from array.pop is the item that is removed from the array